# Subversion Edge fails after setup

Tags: linux, svn

I've set up Subversion Edge two or three times on (linux) servers now, and after an undetermined about of time, it just fails.

I install using the included readme and get everything up and running. I then create repositories and check in/out files on the windows machines (using Tortoise SVN). This will work for some time, and then just stops. The error given when I try to check in/out, update, commit, etc. is:

Commit failed (details follow): 
OPTIONS of 
'http://myserver.mydomain.com:18080/svn/project1/trunk': could not connect to server (http://myserver.mydomain.com:18080)

I should note that I'm not behind any firewall (that I'm aware of), there's no proxy (again, that I'm aware of), and the necessary ports (18080 and 3343) are open. The only thing I can potentially think of is that the failure seems to happen after the linux server is restarted (though I'm not 100% sure of that).

Any advice would a appreciated. I do want to use subversion, as it seems like a good piece of software, but can't implement it for production if it's going to fail shortly thereafter.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check Apache server error log on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server running when you get this error?  Meaning, can you see the httpd process is active and netstat shows port 18080 is allocated?

In case you want to search for help via Google, note that Subversion Edge is simply a web UI to help configure and manage your Apache Subversion server.  The server itself is just plain Apache httpd + Subversion.  Technically, Subversion Edge itself does not even need to be running once Apache is configured and started.

Subversion Edge logs can be accessed via web UI.

The "console" logs are for Subversion Edge itself and will show any errors in starting/stopping the Apache httpd process.

The "error" logs are from Apache httpd and will hold any errors that it logs.

The "access" logs are from Apache httpd and can be helpful in tracking down whether the client request is even reaching the server.

Answer (score 0):

check which user is starting collabnet subversion (csvn). installation and running csvn using root is not supported by csvn. you should install csvn with a non root user account.sometimes in your case, after restarting server, some of the files will get inaccessible, this happens when csvn is installed using the root account, these things are clearly defined in README. also check whether subversion server is started at csvn console. even though csvn console is started during startup, subversion server will be down. hit start button in csvn console to get subversion server started.